# How to set max-height of g element?

Tags: css, svg

I am having issues with setting max height of the `g` element in my svg. Any ideas how I can achieve that? I've tried using css classes, but it didn't worked.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: max-height does not apply to g elements, they always auto size to their contents. What are you actually trying to do?